# Using ajax validation to check if email address already exists before main POST (ASP.NET MVC4)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

In the past I was able to make an async call to a method that looked up a username to see if it already existed in the db and then returned it as JSON as the user was typing into the text box. It has been a long time and I can not seem to find the article that explained how to do this. I currently have everything set up properly E.G.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

as well as in my webconfig

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

and my view model being

```
public class EmailListSignUpViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Compare("Email")]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Email")]
    public string EmailConfirmation { get; set; }
}
```

How would I implement the functionality I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create method in some ControllerName:

```
    public JsonResult IsUniq(string Username) {
            //to do
            return Json("...");
        }
```

And use atribute in ViewModel

```
[Remote("IsUniq", "ControllerName")]
public string Username{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `Remote` attribute on your ViewModel and setup an action method to return true of false as Buboon's answer.

[MVC Remote Validation explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

If you want to do it yourself, you can do this. Listen for the keyup event and send the value of text box to your action method which runs a query againist your db table and return a result which you will evaluate in your `getJSON` callback method and do the needful

```
$(function(){
   $("#Email").keyup(function(){
     var val=$("#Email").val();
     $.getJSON("@Url.Action("Check","User")", { key : val },function(res){
       if(res=="exists")
       {
         $("#someMsgDiv").html("exists");
       }
     });
   });
});
```

Assuming you have Check action method in UserController.

```
public ActionResult Check(string key)
{
  //check in db and return "exists" if record exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do an ajax call to check if you want.  How I validate emails on the client side is with a function

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    if (email == "") {
        return false;
    } else {
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;;
        return email.match(re)
    }
}
```

set this up on your submit button click event and if it returns true do nothing.  If false do a preventDefault.

```
$('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(e){
    if(!validateEmail($('.txtEmail').val())){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions